# R loop: How can I determine the iteration that caused warnings?

Tags: r

I am running a simulation study and need to create an indicator variable for each simulation run that caused R to print warning messages. Since I simulated the data, occasionally the model I am trying to fit might not converge. Hence I need to store the iteration that didn't converge using the indicator variable. I have used "options(warn=1)" so I can see on the console which iteration the model failed. However my code is not properly saving the indicator. I need to run a total of 100 simulations.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
for (s in 1:100){

    myfit=...
    if (!is.null(warnings())) {fail[s]=1} else {fail[s]=0}
}
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Lili

Comment: What do you mean by "not properly saving the indicator?" Did you initialize `fail <- numeric(100)` before the loop? Also I'd suggest explicitly using `tryCatch` here.

Comment: Yes I initialized fail. When I run the code, all values of fail are 0 even though I know several iterations didn't converge. I also used "try()" function but still fail=0 for all iterations. myfit=try(...) if (is(myfit,"try-error")) {fail[s]=1} else {fail[s]=0}

Comment: That's because you're catching warnings, not errors.

Comment: You are right! Not sure how I missed something so obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tryCatch`.

Here's a minimal example that mimics the behavior it sounds like you want:

```
silly_list <- vector("list", 26)
fail <- numeric(26)
for(s in 1:26) {
    l <- letters[s]
    tryCatch(silly_list[[s]] <- factor(1:3, levels = c("a", l, "b")),
             warning = function(w) {
                 print(w)
                 fail[s] <<- 1
             })
}
## <simpleWarning in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels, seq_along(levels))): duplicated levels in factors are deprecated>
## <simpleWarning in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels, seq_along(levels))): duplicated levels in factors are deprecated>
print(fail)
## [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And there's no need to change `options("warn")`.

Comment: Thank you ssdecontrol! I was playing with tryCatch and your example helps a lot. I think I got it to work.

Comment: @Lili the documentation for R's error handling is heinous.